# Denjoy's Counterexample, Semi-Conjugation, Irrational Rotation, $C^1$ Diffeomorphism and Cantor Set in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory, cantor-set

**Introduction to the Geometry of Foliations**, **Part A**. **Gilbert Hector**, **Ulrich Hirsch**. Pages **73**, **74**.

1. Why is the map $J$ **everywhere** continuous from the **right** and continuous from the **left** for points **not** belonging to $G(u_0)$?
2. What do they exactly mean by "the jump of $J$ in $t$ equals $l_n$"?
3. How to prove that $C=\overline{J(\mathbb{R})}$ is actually a **Cantor Set** in $\mathbb{R}$?
   [image]
   [image]

Comment: You need to look at a good book on dynamical systems. You'll find out that all is much simpler than these guys pretend. "subgroup of ${\rm Diff}^\infty_+(\mathbb R)$", wow! Anyway, if you understand the function $J$ than the answer to your first questions is immediate. For the last one make a drawing.

Comment: @JohnB Do you recommend any good book on Dynamical Systems?

Comment: Perhaps you can have a look for example at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3326687/dynamical-systems-for-pure-mathematicians